# Using EncryptSymmetric in Web Analytics Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking for a solution to pass SFMC SubscriberKey value to external application. I'm thinking about encoding it with DES Encryption and using Web Analytics Connector to append all links with it. It's something similar to:

```
par1=%%=URLEncode(EncryptSymmetric('Value', 'des;mode=ecb;padding=zeros', 'KEYID', @null ,@null, @null, @null, @null), 1, 1)=%%
```

Will it degrade overall send time performance significantly? If yes, are there any other ways to pass this value securely without exposing it in the URL and making it readable on external website?